# C# - What happens if I set dll option "embedded interop type" to false or true in vs10?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, com-interop, shell32.dll

Just wanted to know in general what happens in this case, actually the problem is that one of my projects is using shell32.dll which compiles and executes fine on windows 7 PC however fails on other system like windows xp giving an runtime error

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Shell3 2.Shell'

I went through so many web resources but the results did not work for me.

Comment: Don't ask us what the switch does. Flip it and see what light turns on. If you can't see anything, look for its manual.

Comment: Well what error is it giving? Any time you're asking a question which involves an error, it's *imperative* that you include the error itself in the question.

Comment: I can tons of web results for this. What exactly did you search?

Comment: This is an XY question.  The error doesn't have anything to do with the option.

Comment: Please edit all of this information into the question, rather than just including it in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The switch is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997297.aspx).